# How to turn off geany message window by default?

Tags: editor, geany

I use [geany](http://www.geany.org/) to do simple text editing and viewing. But its message window takes half the area and is useless for me. I want to turn it off when I run geany. I know [there is a command option `--no-msgwin` for that](http://www.geany.org/manual/0.18.1/index.html#command-line-options). But how can I tell geany not to show message window if I start geany from right click menu? Is there such a configuration option?

Or, can I can configure geany to have a minimal message window size when geany starts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question.. you want to hide this window:

[image]

Go to the MenuBar **View -> Show Message Window** and untick it.

[image]

Then close geany and open a file with the right click menu.

[image]

No more Message Window.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can go under Edit --> Preferences, and choose to suppress status messages.

[image]

Also Un-check the items shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. But that's not what I want. I want the message window to disappear (e.g. when you run "geany -m")

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Now I only have the annoying term window left at the message window place. I guess now I need to figure out how to turn off the term.